# Magic Number to calculate number of rounds for M-R in FIPS 186-4

Tags: implementation, prime-numbers, nist

In [Fips 186-4](https://csrc.nist.gov/news/2015/fips-186-4-rfc-nist-recommended-elliptic-curves), there is an algorithm in Appendix F (at page 117 in my copy of the 2013 version) to calculate the number of rounds of the [Miller-Rabin primality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller%E2%80%93Rabin_primality_test) test to random bases.

- Does anybody know where the magic number `2.00743` comes from or do I *really* have to work through the paper [Average Case Error Estimates for the Strong Probable Prime Test](https://www.ams.org/mcom/1993-61-203/S0025-5718-1993-1189518-9/S0025-5718-1993-1189518-9.pdf) by I. Damgard et. al

Comment: The formula with the $2.00743\cdot\ln(2)$ factor remains online despite some ongoing mess, thanks to a [webarchive for FIPS 186-4](https://web.archive.org/web/20181226075209if_/https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/FIPS/NIST.FIPS.186-4.pdf#page=126). Importantly, that formula assumes the candidate prime tested is random.

Comment: @fgrieu I looked at the Fips, but couldn't find where the constant $2.00743$ occurs. They only say `The ideas of paper [1] were applied...` But there is no direct result from the article, too

Comment: @kelalaka: I found _where_ it occurs (and linked to it), but not _how_. I tried a few straightforward applications of the formulas in the reference paper, but failed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This constant is used to approximate $(\pi(2^k) - \pi(2^{k-1}))^{-1}$, as shown in (4.1) of the Damgard et al. paper:

$$
p_{k,t} \le (\pi(2^k) - \pi(2^{k-1}))^{-1} \sum\nolimits'_{n \in M_k} \bar{\alpha}(n)^t \,.
$$

Most of the formula in the NIST document, between the square brackets, is dealing with the $\bar\alpha$ sum. The left side is dealing with the prime difference approximation.
From Propositon 2 of the Damgard et al. paper, we have

$$
(\pi(2^k) - \pi(2^{k-1})) > 0.71867 \frac{2^k}{k}\,,
$$

from which we can replace $(\pi(2^k) - \pi(2^{k-1}))^{-1}$ by $\frac{1}{0.71867 2^k / k}$ $=$ $1.39145 \cdot k \cdot 2^{-k}$ $=$ $2.00743 \cdot \ln(2) \cdot k \cdot 2^{-k} $.

The $\ln(2)$ term probably comes from the approximation $\pi(2^k) \approx \frac{2^k}{ \ln(2^k)} = \frac{2^k}{k \cdot \ln(2)}$, as in the proof of Proposition 2.